# How to deploy windows form applications on a winRT tablet (Surface)?

Tags: winforms, windows-rt

Is it possible to deploy a windows form application to a winRT tablet? Say surface.

The target platform for a win form application is either x86 or x64 and not ARM. Hence I am not able to build a win form application for the tablet and hence could not be executed on the tablet.

Thanks,
Soorya

Comment: Why would you want to do that? just write the application in WinRT and you're good to go.

Comment: I want to write a device watcher win service to be deployed on the tablet which would launch a metro app once it finds the appropriate BT devices in proximity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a supported scenario. You can only develop Windows Store (Windows Runtime also known as WinRT) applications to an ARM device running Windows RT. Windows Forms (aka. WinForms) applications are desktop applications leveraging the legacy desktop Windows API/WinAPI/Win32.

Comment: Thanks Filip. That's a bummer though